# How to find the process id that is running my Java Application

Tags: java, process, background, window, tasklist

I know it's quite basic question but still I am not clear about it. When I am running my jar file in background in windows using below command using bat file:

```
start javaw -jar myApp.jar
```

It start the application in background but is there any way to check if it's running or how would i kill it if I want to.

In Linux We can do `ps -ef| grep JarName` and then we can call kill command.How to do the same in windows. `tasklist` command shows java.exe instead of jar name.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `jps` to view current Java processes, then pass the output to `taskkill`. Call this script with the full `package.Classname` of the process to kill:

```
rem Run as killpid.cmd package.Classname 
@echo off
jps -l |findstr %1 > %TEMP%\pid.txt

echo FOUND:
type %TEMP%\pid.txt

for /f %%i in (%TEMP%\pid.txt) do taskkill /pid %%i
```